# How to call a method with parameters from an optional object in java

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Let's consider the following class

```
class A{
    void met(int i){
       //do somthing
    }
}
```

and let's consider that we have an optional object of this class like:

```
Optional<A> a;
```

is it possible to call the method `met` on the object `a` without the need to check whether `a` refers to a full object or just empty (`null`). Something like:

```
a.map(A::met(5));
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't compile. How can this be done?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when a is empty?

Comment: the method will not be called

Comment: so as if this line of code `a.map(A::met(5));` doesn't exist

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two reasons why this can't work:

```
a.map(A::met(5));
```

1. `met` returns nothing, and `map` must map the input `Optional` to an output `Optional`.
2. method references don't take arguments, so you should use a lambda expression.

What you need is :

```
a.ifPresent(x->x.met(5));
```

Another option :

```
a.orElse(new A()).met(5);
```

This will execute `met(5)` on a dummy instance if `a` is empty, so it's probably not the best way.

Comment: @Anas It's just an arbitrary variable name whose type is A. It's a way to refer to the instance held by your Optional<A>

Comment: Depending on semantics, the latter option could work well with the Null Object pattern.